# how to validate email addresses separated by comma

Tags: regex

I want to match regular expression for multiple emails separated by comma,
I want to match:

```
abc123@gmail.com,xyz56_@gmail.co.in
```

It should match both email id's.

On the other hand, It should not match:

```
abc,123@gmail.com, xy,z123@gmail.co.in
```

I have written my regex:

```
\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*,?
```

What should I do to achieve this?

Comment: It might be easier to split the input by a comma and validate each of the items

Comment: It depends on how good you want to be at validating emails, from just checking that the part contains a `@` up to sophisticated softwares, passing by [this regex](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Comment: can you help me to write this type of regex

Comment: @NicoHaase and @Aaron gave you the best anwser, if you really want to parse email in an accurate way, the best you can do is: 1. Split input by `,`,  2. use the [RCF's pattern](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) on each item to valide. Btw, you better compile your pattern first (`pattern = re.compile("THEPATTERN")`)

Comment: Here is [your pattern that is adjusted to match comma separated emails](https://regex101.com/r/fhhAjg/1).

Comment: Why should something like `123@gmail.com` not match?